# Установить тип boolean вместо bit в выборке select

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, case

В исходной таблице есть колонка тип bit принимающая значения 0, 1, или null.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

запрос

```
select *, 
case 
   when a.is_credit_cmp = 0 then false
   when a.is_credit_cmp = 1 then true
   when a.is_credit_cmp = NULL then NULL
end
as is_credit_bool
from emitent as a;
```

ругается на invalid column false

если взять в кавычки false и true то строиться таблица где колонка is_credit_bool varhar а мне нужно чтобы был boolean.

как этого добиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если использовать вместо `false`->`FALSE`, ситуация аналогичная?

Comment: да аналогичная ситуация

Comment: Что-то сказки рассказываете. Во-первых, `a.is_credit_cmp = 0` обязано породить ошибку, что BIT нельзя сравнить с INTEGER. Во-вторых, `a.is_credit_cmp = NULL` вообще лютый бред.

Comment: нет никаких ошибок при выполнении. приложил скрин фрагмента что строиться при выборке. но мне не ясно как сделать bool тип в колонке is_credit_bool

Comment: Значит, используемый клиент выполняет дополнительную работу и добавляет нужные преобразования.

Comment: возможно. я dbeaver использую. почему то при выполнении ругается на :: incorrect syntax near '::' и если CAST(1 AS BIT) тоже(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, is_credit_cmp = 1::BIT is_credit_bool
FROM emitent;
```

| id | is_credit_cmp | is_credit_bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | f |
| 2 | 1 | t |
| 3 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x5XGEMOE)